# Are there any errata corrections for the epic Paladin's Turn Undead and Remove Disease progressions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, paladin, epic-tier, errata

In my campaign the level 20 paladin PC is about to hit level 21 and I noticed 3.5 DMG page 208 states:

> Turn Undead (Su):The paladin turns undead as a cleric of two levels
>   lower, as normal.

However I believe this is incorrect because the PHB states that the paladin turns undead as a cleric three levels lower.

Also states:

> Remove Disease (Sp): The epic paladin can use remove disease one
>   additional time per week for every three levels higher than 18th
>   (7/week at 21st, 8/week at 24th, and so on).

I believe this is also incorrect because the PHB states that the paladin should gain additional uses of that feature for every 3 levels above 6th (so 6/week at 21st level).

I've checked Dungeon Master's Guide v.3.5 Errata 3/10/04 Version 032004 there's no mention of these discrepancies. I've web searched for any mention of these two items being mistakes and still I found nothing.

Does anyone know if these are in fact mistakes and if so where I might find reference to these items being corrected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It's a holdover from D&D 3.0 that never got an errata.

The *Epic Level Handbook* which introduced epic paladin is a D&D 3.0 book. The [paladin in D&D 3.0](https://www.dragon.ee/30srd/paladin.htm) used turn undead as a cleric of two levels lower. The [D&D 3.5 paladin](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm) uses it as three levels lower.

However, the Epic Level Handbook [v3.5 update document](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/DnD35_Epic_Handbook.zip) did not change the paladin progression to adjust for the change. In fact, the same is true for all of its base class epic progressions:

> The epic-level class progressions for the core classes are unchanged.

The Epic Paladin progression in the D&D 3.5 *Dungeon Master's Guide* does not change from the 3.0 Epic Paladin, and as you mentioned, the errata for that document doesn't change it.

Therefore, the turn undead progression of two levels below the cleric is technically valid for the 3.5 epic paladin, even though it's not for the 3.5 base paladin. This is, of course, probably an oversight on the part of the writers, and it would be reasonable to house-rule this to correct it so that the progression lines up as expected in 3.5.

The same thing occurs with Remove Disease, since the 3.0 paladin gets that 1/day starting at level 3, whereas the 3.5 paladin doesn't get Remove Disease until level 6, giving the 3.0 paladin an extra use of that ability which was inadvertently carried over to the 3.5 Epic Paladin progression.